# get Post like count with Facebook AP

Tags: facebook-graph-api, count, facebook-like

i am trying to retrieve a facebook POSTs information (ie: LIKE count) using the facebook API

The URL which used to work was in this format:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=[AUTHOR_ID]_[POST_ID]
```

*(author and post ID omitted on purpose)*

Now it returns a false data feed. Has the URL structure to retrieve POST information changed?

Comment: Did you check their documentation?

Answer (score 1):

With **October 2013 Breaking Changes**, likes.count field is no longer available in the feed.

You need to make a call for each POST_ID with the summary field enabled.

https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes?summary=true&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX

There will be a "summary" element with a "total_count" field.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that still works for me - just tested with one of my posts:

```
 "id": "<SNIP>", 
   //removed most fields
   "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/X/posts/Y"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/X/posts/Y"
    }
  ], 
  "type": "photo", 
  "status_type": "added_photos", 
  "object_id": "SNIP", 
  "application": {
    "name": "Facebook for Android", 
    "namespace": "fbandroid", 
    "id": "350685531728"
  }, 
  "created_time": "2012-10-12T06:52:10+0000", 
  "updated_time": "2012-10-12T07:48:34+0000", 
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      // four likers' details
    ], 
    "count": 28
  }, 
//snip
```

Check you still have `read_stream` [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) from your user, that the post hasn't been deleted, etc

Comment: thanks for the response - yes the POST is still there and both author and post IDs are valid.  the facebook account is for a company...is it possible that with the new facebook interface a permission setting was changed to block this information from being readable?

Comment: how would the owner of the facebook account allow "read_stream" permissions?  guessing it's done through the account settings?

Comment: No, through the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) flow you make them go through so you can access their data - if you're using a page access token that's probably not necessary because the page access token can implicitly access all of that page's data

Comment: so something like this would allow me to get the POST information:   graph.facebook.com/?ids=[AUTHOR_ID]_[POST_ID]?access_token=[access_token]   if so, how/where do i acquire the access_token value?